# Column alias from Extract function

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I have some code below which works to extract the year from a datefield, but it brings back all years from the table, ie 2011, 2012, 2013, where as I only want 2013. This is the basic query that works for the years:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startDate) FROM events_events where EventOwnerId = 206
```

This is my query where I tried to create an alias and return only 2013 years but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startDate) as d_year 
FROM events_events 
where EventOwnerId = 206 AND d_year = 2013
```

Comment: You may also be interested in the [YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

You *could* repeat the `EXTRACT()` function within your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startDate) AS d_year
FROM   events_events
WHERE  EventOwnerId = 206
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startDate) = 2013
```

However this is not particularly efficient, as MySQL must calculate the result of the function for every record (which necessitates a full table scan).  If an index on `startDate` is to be used, it would be better to filter for dates within the desired range:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startDate) AS d_year
FROM   events_events
WHERE  EventOwnerId = 206
   AND startDate >= '2013-01-01'
   AND startDate <  '2014-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startDate) as d_year 
FROM events_events 
where EventOwnerId = 206 AND EXTRACT(YEAR from startDate) = 2013
```